# How to Create MultiSelect dropdown with checkboxes in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use the asp.net mvc multiselect dropdown with checkbox.
How can I add checkboxes in the simplest way ?
I am using bootstrap v3

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => Model.DepDashTaskLists[i].BusinessRuleAnswers, new MultiSelectList(slh.GetRegistrationAnswerLookup(Model.DepDashTaskLists[i].BusinessRuleQuestion1), "Value", "Text", Model.DepDashTaskLists[i].BusinessRuleAnswers), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "RuleQuestionListBoxAnswer_" + @Model.DepDashTaskLists[i].TaskId, @rows = "2", @columns = "40" })
```

Comment: Please check this link https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect and this link might be helpful for you 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/multiselect-dropdown-with-checkboxes-using-jquery-in-mvc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample, base on @jishan siddique suggestion.
You can visit the link to refer more: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Model

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Products { get; set; }
    public int[] ProductIds { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{           
    var model = new ProductViewModel()
    {
        Products = GetProducts()
    };            
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel product)
{                
    return View(product);
}

private List<SelectListItem> GetProducts()
{
    var data = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = "1", Text = "Tomato"
        },
        new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = "2", Text = "Orange"
        },
        new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = "3", Text = "Potato"
        }
    };
    return data;
}
```

Views

```
@model CiberProject.ViewModels.ProductViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";    
}

<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Label("Products:")
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ProductIds, Model.Products, new { @class = "listbox" })
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.listbox').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: 'The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.'

Comment: I am also getting an error  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function.

Comment: @Curious-programmer: You don't use _Layout for this form?

Comment: @Curious-programmer: Add @Html.AntiForgeryToken() inside Form. If you need, I will edit my answer, my friend.

Comment: Appreciate the help, I have added one related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569599/bootstrap-multiselect-with-checkbox-trigger-from-the-listbox-itself

Answer (score 1):

**1**  First of all load the jQuery and Bootstrap framework into your HTML document.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**2** After this, include the Bootstrap `multiselect's` CSS and JavaScript file to your page.

```
<!-- Bootstrap Multiselect CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">

<!-- Bootstrap Multiselect JS -->
<script data-main="dist/js/" src="js/require.min.js"></script>
```

**3** Now create HTML select element with your list of options with a unique id. Just like below.

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Option one">Option one</option>
<option value="Option two">Option two</option>
<option value="Option three">Option three</option>
<option value="Option four">Option four</option>
<option value="Option five">Option five</option>
<option value="Option six">Option six</option>
</select>
```

**4** And Finally call the plugin to active the multiselect.

```
<script>
require(['bootstrap-multiselect'], function(purchase){
$('#mySelect').multiselect();
});
</script>
```

You can visit the link to refer more: https://www.codehim.com/demo/bootstrap-multiselect-dropdown/